# Как сделать таймер, отсчитывающий 24 часа с 00:00 до 23:59:59?

Tags: jquery

Как сделать таймер, отсчитывающий 24 часа с 00:00:00 до 23:59:59?
Если я зашел на сайт в 10:30:45, то на таймере показывает 13:29:14. Если я зашел в 00:01:00, то на таймере 23:58:00.

HTML:

```
<div class="timer">
    <div class="timer_item"><span class="hours">00</span><br>часов</div>
    <div class="timer_item"><span class="minutes">00</span><br>минут</div>
    <div class="timer_item"><span class="seconds">00</span><br>секунд</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Заголовок `00:00 -> 23:59` и приведённые примеры противоречат друг другу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала нужно зафиксировать момент времени. Либо начала, либо конца. И уже от него всё отсчитывать.

```js
let out = document.getElementById('timepassed');
let start = new Date(out.dataset.start);

const timer = () => {
  let diff = Date.now() - start.getTime();
  diff /= 1e3; // мс -> с
  out.innerText = [
    diff / 3600 % 24 |0, // hours
    diff / 60 % 60   |0, // minutes
    diff / 1 % 60    |0  // seconds
  ].map(d => d<10?'0'+d:d).join(':');
};

let i = setInterval(timer, 450);
timer();
```

```html
<span id="timepassed" 
      data-start="2017-03-24 01:30:00">
  00:00:00
</span>
```

---

Если же нужно отсчитывать время оставшееся до события:

```js
let out = document.getElementById('timeleft');
let start = new Date(out.dataset.end);

let timer = () => {
  let diff = start.getTime() - Date.now();
  if (diff <= 0) return clearInterval(i); // Конец
  diff /= 1e3; // мс -> с
  out.innerText = [
    diff / 3600 % 24 |0, // hours
    diff / 60 % 60   |0, // minutes
    diff / 1 % 60    |0  // seconds
  ].map(d => d<10?'0'+d:d).join(':');
};

let i = setInterval(timer, 450);
timer();
```

```html
<span id="timeleft" 
      data-end="2030-03-25 00:00:00"> <!-- Дата события выбрана в 2030, чтобы сниппет не потерял актульность завтра :) -->
  00:00:00
</span>
```

---

Отсчёт до полуночи без привязки к событиям:

```js
let out = document.getElementById('timeleft');
const fullday = 24*3600e3;
const tzdiff = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60e3;

let timer = () => {
  // До полуночи в UTC
  // let diff = fullday - Date.now() % fullday; 
  
  // До полуночи в часовом поясе клиента
  let diff = fullday - (Date.now()-tzdiff) % fullday
  
  if (diff <= 0) return clearInterval(i); // Конец
  diff /= 1e3; // мс -> с
  out.innerText = [
    diff / 3600 % 24 |0, // hours
    diff / 60 % 60   |0, // minutes
    diff / 1 % 60    |0  // seconds
  ].map(d => d<10?'0'+d:d).join(':');
};

let i = setInterval(timer, 450);
timer();
```

```html
<span id="timeleft">00:00:00</span>
```

Comment: А что значит e3 и let i = setInterval(timer, 450); ?

Comment: Запись числа с плавающей запятой: https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/ `let` - аналог `var`

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, вы можете перевести код на старый добрый es5 с помощью транспайлера. Есть даже [онлайн-сервисы](https://es6console.com/) Экспоненциальная запись числа: `12e3 = 12*10^3 = 12000`